# Calculate effect size (e.g., Pearson r) from the output of a multiple regression

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, effect-size, pearson-r

I'm looking at a multiple regression analysis in which I'm only interested in 1 of the several variables included in the model. However, the bivariate associations are not reported. I'm wondering if I can somehow convert the standardized regression coefficient into a Pearson $r$? Maybe there's someway to get a Pearson $r$ from the change in $R^2$?

Comment: The coefficients themselves give you the effect size. Also, effect size and goodness of fit (which is what R^2 is telling you) are not the same thing.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can only get the Pearson r statistic from a linear regression model with 1 covariate. You cannot do this with multiple linear regression. However, if all you want is a matrix of correlation coefficients, any statistical software should have a command/button for that independent of the regression output.

Comment: As I also mentioned below, this isn't my data. Instead, I'm trying to obtain a pearson r from a multiple regression reported in a publication.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot get a bivariate correlation coefficient $r$ from the output of a multiple regression, whether the data were originally standardised or not. The information about the covariance between the predictors is unavailable to you, and that will influence the change in $R^2$ between models with and without the predictor of interest.

Note, however, that if your interest is in *effect size* in general, the regression coefficient already provides you with one measure of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can input the dataframe with those columns for which you need bivariate associations and use the `cor()` in R to get the job done.
If you also need the significance of correlation between two variables, you can use `rcorr()` Hmisc library as follows

```
library(Himsc)
df<-your_data_frame
cor_matrix<-rcorr(as.matrix(df),type="pearson")
cor_values<-cor_matrix$r
cor_p_values<-cor_matrix$p
```

Comment: The problem here is that this isn't my data. I'm trying to obtain a pearson r from a multiple regression reported in a publication.